# Create Google API key on Laravel homestead

Tags: google-maps, laravel, google-api, homestead

I'm developing my application using Laravel Homestead virtual server. Of course I've rewrite my site from http://192.168.0... to http://myaplication.app. Then I need to create a Google Api key to implement Google maps on my project but I can not generate my api key.

This is how I am doing that:

[image: Google maps configuration]

But Google throws me an error telling me the application is not authorized. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Google need a regular domain like app.com for "URIS de redireccionamiento". Google doesn't allow local Ip's (e.g. 192.168...).

[image: here is an example of my app]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, because you are in development you have to add http://localhost in Javacript origins and leave blank other form fields where Google asks for ips or URls.